# two i2c sensors cant work simultaneously

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, i2c

I tested all sensors onboard GY86(MPU6050-HMC8553-MS5611) and tiny RTC module ds1307 separately with an Arduino Uno.
 Now I am trying to connect both of them and get results simultaneously.
Exactly when i connect DS1307 to I2C bus,suddenly i get (MPU6050 connection failed error). It seems they cant work together. They work separately fine. 
This is the code for initialization:

```
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <MS5611.h>
RTC_DS1307 RTC;
double startTime;
MPU6050 accelgyro(0x68);
MPU6050 mpu = accelgyro;
```

This code  executes in setup function:

```
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
    Wire.begin();
    TWBR = 24; // 400kHz I2C clock (200kHz if CPU is 8MHz). Comment this line if having compilation difficulties with TWBR.
#elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
    Fastwire::setup(400, true);
#endif
Serial.begin(115200);
while (!Serial) // wait for Leonardo enumeration, others continue immediately
   ;
mpu.initialize();
Serial.println(mpu.testConnection() ? F("") : F("MPU6050 connection failed"));

mpu.setI2CMasterModeEnabled(false);
mpu.setI2CBypassEnabled(true) ;
mpu.setSleepEnabled(false);

RTC.begin();
DateTime now = RTC.now();
DateTime nowSetup = RTC.now();
double startTime = nowSetup.unixtime();
if (! RTC.isrunning()) {
   Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
}
```

What can  be the problem?

Comment: Just delete the question, since you solved it.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem. Arduino couldn't supply enough current so I used an external power supply and it is working perfectly.